# saving intermediate steps in gremlin

Tags: groovy, neo4j, gremlin

I am writing a query which should detect certain loops within a graph, which means that I need I need to assign names to certain nodes within the path so that I can compare nodes later in the path with the saved ones. for example A -> B -> C -> A. Is this possible within gremlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Except-Retain-Pattern

where you keep a list of previously traversed vertices and then utilize that list later in the traversal.